# Is there a good git client for Mac OS X that has all the bells and whistles of Conerstone or Versions for Subversion?

Tags: git, macos, user-interface, client

I am wiling to pay good money for it if it has all the most common features and polished look. Also, I've seen gitx and I am asking if there are any other GUI clients besides gitx.

Comment: I tend to use GitX for history browsing and DTerm (command line) for merges and things. It's been working fine.

Comment: Cornerstone/Versions have "bells and whistles"? I just thought they are good-looking, but feature-limited SVN clients.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this [overview of all graphical Git clients](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#Graphical_Interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

XCode 4 has some very nice git support. If you're registered with the Mac Developer program you can download a copy of the beta.

Although, looking at the homepages of Cornerstone and Versions it seems that they have quite a lot more "version-control related features" than XCode 4; but XCode has the advantage of integrating version control into the editing process. (Check out the WWDC session video on it to see what I mean.) So I guess it depends quite a lot on whether or not you currently use some version of XCode for your coding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm partial to [Sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com), myself.

Answer (score 0):

Gitti look promising... is in private beta at the moment: http://www.gittiapp.com/